# double precision in JAVA

Tags: java, double, precision

I have to round off my result to the nearest fo 0.05 ie(6.34 to 6.35 and 6.37 to 6.4)
    So I created myRound  function.
    When I wrote test to see the function, Its fails.

```
double rate=14.99;
double  percentage=10;
double roundedCost=(rate*percentage)/100; //round off to the nearest value. 
double finalRate = rate+myRound(roundedCost,2);

if(finalRate==16.49)
    System.out.println("Its proper");
else
    System.out.println("Wrong");
```

The reason is precission value of double.
    **How to correct the precision.**

```
public double myRound(double value,int roundRange)
{
    double hundredMultiple=(float) Math.pow(10, roundRange);
    int rangeValue= (int) (value*hundredMultiple);
    int tempValue= rangeValue%10;
    if(tempValue<5)
        tempValue=5-tempValue;
    else
        tempValue=10-tempValue;
    rangeValue=rangeValue+tempValue;

    return rangeValue/hundredMultiple;

}
```

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ to understand the root of the problem and possible fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much shorter function is to do.

```
public static double round(double v, int precision) {
     long t = TENS[precision]; // contains powers of ten.
     return (double) (long) (v > 0 ? v * t + 0.5 : v * t - 0.5) / t;
}
```

This works for numbers with less than 18 significant digits (over your precision) e.g. for 2 decimal places, the number should be less than 10^16.

BTW, You should always round the final answer (possibly only round the final answer).  This is because `x + round(y, 2)` may not be equal to `round(x + y, 2)`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're trying to perform operations which are interested in *decimal digits*. That doesn't fit well with a *binary* floating point type. You should use `BigDecimal`, which is a decimal-based representation.

Just as an idea of why your current scheme won't work, if you write:

```
double d = 0.1;
```

the value of `d` isn't *actually* 0.1 - it's the closest 64-bit IEEE 754 binary floating point value to 0.1. It'll be very *close* in value to 0.1, but it won't be 0.1.